# Book with a flooded world, structures on stilts above the oceans

Tags: story-identification, books

OK this is a massively long shot here but hey ho someone might have a clue.

I remember picking this book up at a jumble sale as a kid (c.1990 so published before then, book definitely felt older).

I was in the UK.

I stood there read a few pages if not a few chapters whilst hanging around for a parent. I don’t remember actually buying the thing or reading it to completion but who knows.

This is what I remember;

- Probably earth-based, although alternative world also possible
- Planet was mostly (if not completely) flooded
- Far future
- Most (mega) structures built on stilts above the oceans
- Possibly it was just one massive mega structure that went in a ring around the planet
- The front cover depicted a portion of a large white ring structure on the planet, standing on stilts above the ocean. I seem to remember some sort of craft depicted also.
- The large structure had red detailing.
- Seemed like a post-scarcity society of some description.
- Not ring world stuff as the structures were definitely on-planet.

I have no reason to believe this was intended as young-adult fiction.

I know this isn’t a lot to go on but there’s a chance someone has an idea so grateful for any thoughts - I might even discover new interesting works to read in the process!

Thanks in advance!

*EDITS - What this book is not! (updated as suggestions come in)*

- *The Drowned World* by J. G. Ballard
- David Wingrove's *Chung Kuo* novels
- *Tatja Grimm's World* by Vernor Vinge

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: From the context, is it safe to assume this was young adult fiction?

Comment: @Ross I have no reason to believe it was, it was at a stall at a thrift market type affair where there would have been no discernible order to topics. In any case I never went for children's books I found them boring.

Comment: If instead of a truly advanced society with megastructures it was a rudimentary society ruled by a priesthood, I might know what it is. But it doesn't completely match your description... just the flooded world :P